# importing hex stream into wireshark

Tags: wireshark, hexdump

I have a 64 byte hex stream of a frame-

```
000A959D6816000A959A651508004500002E000000004006AF160A010101C0A8000A11D71EC6000000000000000050000000AD840000000102030405CC904CE3
```

How can I import it into Wireshark and see the whole packet?
The option of importing hex dump doesn't seems to work in my case, if I save this stream into a text file and load it.

Answer (score 10):

Since this hex stream is in hex, and for hex to hexdump conversion, `od` doesn't seems to work. So the solution would be to convert this hex back to binary, and then use `od -Ax -tx1 -v [file]` on that binary file.

```
xxd -r -p [hexfile] [binaryfile]
od -Ax -tx1 -v [binaryfile]
```

Note: Use the combination `-r` `-p` to read plain hexadecimal dumps without line number information and without a particular column layout.

Comment: See the Wireshark docs where they talk about the `od` command https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOImportSection.html

Comment: This can be streamlined into one command: `xxd -r -p [hexstringfile] | od -Ax -tx1 > [hexdumpfile]`. Also omitting the filenames (and `>`) will make it use standard input and output.

Answer (score 2):

A hex stream can be transformed into an `od`-like format filtering through a couple `coreutils`. The output can be fed into `text2pcap`, for example, to also set a link-layer type.

```sh
{ echo -n "0000 "; echo $hex_stream | fold -w 2 | paste -sd ' '; } | text2pcap -l 147 - $file
```

`hex_stream` is the data to be dissected and `file` is the `pcap` file to be written by `text2pcap`. I use this as part of a script that generates a temporary `pcap` from a hex stream and invokes `tshark` to dissect it - this gives me the dissection result immediately with no manual intervention.

[How to Dissect Anything](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDissectAnything) page in the Wireshark wiki has further information on dissection of arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

If you format your hex string as shown in [this](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOImportSection.html) page, you should be able to use the `Import from Hex Dump` dialog to import the file you've created.

Comment: Thanks, but this "od -Ax -tx1 -v [FILE]" command is dumping my hex stream in octal format. I tried all other options of "od" but no luck. So I manually formatted the stream by adding spaces and offsetting it by 8 bytes, which worked.

It's a single frame so it's no worry but manually doing all this stuff on large hex data would be a pain. Please let me know if you know how to convert hex stream to hex dump.

Comment: @tcpip Awesome. That's pretty much what I meant, sorry if that wasn't clear.